# Fill responsive svg with background image with preserving ratio

Tags: html, svg, background

I try to draw a svg in my HTML Code to have a specific path/object with an background image. 
The object should be a little bit responsive (using bootstrap), but filled with the image and the image should preseve its ratio.

```
<svg width="100%" height="370px" viewBox="0 0 1148.942 598.47"  preserveAspectRatio="none"  >
    <defs>
      <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="1153" height="680">
        <image xlink:href="images/headerBackground.png" x="0" y="0" width="1153" height="680" />
      </pattern>
    </defs>
        <path fill="url(#img1)" d="M1145.237,3.395H3.379v592c0,0,247.108-160.416,1141-99L1145.237,3.395z"/>
    </svg>
```

You can see it here in the live demo: 
<strike>https://liveweave.com/N5nib6</strike>
https://jsfiddle.net/zyyvd86g/

Maybe anybody can help? I hope the problem is clear enough.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your liveweave demo does not match your question.  Can you fix that please?

Comment: I changed the link. I don't know, why it does not work as expected. On my computer I see the right version, but not on my smartphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use max-width:100% for the svg element and div element wrap on this svg.
You can get the responsive image

```css
div {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
svg {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <svg width="100%" height="370px" viewBox="0 0 1148.942 598.47"  preserveAspectRatio="none"  >
    <defs>
      <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="1153" height="680">
        <image xlink:href="images/headerBackground.png" x="0" y="0" width="1153" height="680" />
      </pattern>
    </defs>
        <path fill="url(#img1)" d="M1145.237,3.395H3.379v592c0,0,247.108-160.416,1141-99L1145.237,3.395z"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO opinion, the simple solution to your problem is to use a different `preserveAspectRatio` on your SVG.

Using `preserveAspectRatio="none"` is going to stretch your SVG and cause problems.

I'm assuming you want to keep the shape of the "swoop" on the bottom of your path.  Correct?

If that is the case, you might prefer to use

```
preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax slice"
```

instead.  This scales the SVG up to fill the full width of the SVG viewport, whilst keeping the aspect ratio the same, **and** keeping the bottom of the SVG viewBox on screen.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="370px" viewBox="0 0 1148.942 598.47" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax slice">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="1153" height="680">
     <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/1153/680/" x="0" y="0" width="1153" height="680" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <path fill="url(#img1)" d="M1145.237,3.395H3.379v592c0,0,247.108-160.416,1141-99L1145.237,3.395z"/>
</svg>
```